# Set Powershell script language

Tags: powershell-extensions

I would like to know if there's a way to set the current script's context language through code. 
I know there's a way to set it in the ISE but I need some code that could override it and force a specific script to always run in a certain language.

Something like this:

```
$Context.Language = [Sitecore.Data.Managers.LanguageManager]::GetLanguage("nl")
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set context language using

**Syntax:**

```
 #get language to be switched
 $lan = [Sitecore.Globalization.Language]::Parse("$switchLanguage")
 #Set Context language, use 'ispersistent' parameter based on your requirement.in my case it should be for a while i.e. creation of master content.
 [Sitecore.Context]::SetLanguage( $lan,$false)
```

Below is one of the PS script used in one of my project. :)

**Snapshot:**

[image: PS script to switch context lang to en-US from en(default)]

**Actual Script:**

```
$defaultContextLang = [Sitecore.Context]::Language.Name
Write-Host "Default context language is '$defaultContextLang'"
$switchLanguage = "en-US"
$lan = [Sitecore.Globalization.Language]::Parse("$switchLanguage")
 [Sitecore.Context]::SetLanguage( $lan,$false)
 $switchedContextLang = [Sitecore.Context]::Language.Name
 Write-Host "Switched context language is '$switchedContextLang'"
```